# String aggregation with two columns using JSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, string-aggregation

My result contains data like:

```
CustomerId | Rating (Star) | RatingCount
  1        |   1           |   20
  1        |   2           |   15
  1        |   3           |   4
  1        |   4           |   30
  1        |   5           |   36
  2        |   1           |   5
  2        |   2           |   4
  2        |   5           |   10
```

But I would like to transform the result as:

```
CustomerId  | CustomerRatings
   1        | { "1": 20, "2": 15, "3": 4 , "4": 30, "5": 36 }
   2        | { "1": 5, "2": 4, "5": 10 }
```

I have used the FOR JSON Path function to transfrom the data as

```
@JSONString = {"_":"1","__":20},{"_":"2","__":15},{"_":"3","__":4},{"_":"4","__":30},{"_":"5","__":36}
```

Then used the replace method to get the actual result.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@JSONString,'"_":',''),',"__":',':'),'},{',',')

{"1":20,"2":15,"3":4,"4":30,"5":36}
```

Is there a better way to achieve that? I started using SQL server 2016 last couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that rating is always between 1 and 5:

```sql
SELECT CustomerId, (
    SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN Rating = 1 THEN RatingCount END) AS [1]
         , MIN(CASE WHEN Rating = 2 THEN RatingCount END) AS [2]
         , MIN(CASE WHEN Rating = 3 THEN RatingCount END) AS [3]
         , MIN(CASE WHEN Rating = 4 THEN RatingCount END) AS [4]
         , MIN(CASE WHEN Rating = 5 THEN RatingCount END) AS [5]
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.CustomerId = t.CustomerId
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
FROM t
GROUP BY CustomerId
```

Use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` option to include null values, or `COALESCE(..., 0)` to convert null to zeros.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29402712c57cf99c4dddf6f8dd621ad3)

Comment: Can you please look at this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=80a25972ad80d01b0fc0f39cc8f9fcc9
I would like to get the result like {"APV": {"1":1,"3":3,"4":24,"5":95}, "VN":{"1":3,"5":25} }

Comment: Yes your a correct,This is for returning data, not storing data.